# apache2 service is not active how can make it active

Tags: apache2

How can i made apache2 service active? when i tried to start apache2 service it gives me this error.apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.help me on this.on my localhost/phpmyadmin
403 Forbidden
nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Have you tried `systemctl restart apache2`?  What do you get for `systemctl status apache2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if apache2 service is already enabled by

```
sudo service --status-all | grep apache2
```

The output should be

```
[ + ]  apache2
```

If it is not already enabled you can do

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 enable
```